# Python - playing mp3 files

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the solutions are working for me.

I use Arch Linux.

Here's what I've tried / looked into:

1. pyglet - does not work; their own website says 'Linux users have the option of choosing    between OpenAL and ALSA for audio output. Unfortunately both implementations have severe limitations or implementation bugs that are outside the scope of pyglet's control.'
2. pymedia - not supported any more; even the examples on their website do not work.
3. pygame - from their website: 'Be aware that MP3 support is limited'.
4. wx.media - this actually works, but the rest of my 'application' is in tkinter.
5. mp3play - only win32

Please help.

Comment: same here,cannot find a satisfying lib.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`sfml`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php), it has [audio support](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Music.php) - there are [Python bindings for the latest version](https://github.com/bastienleonard/pysfml-cython), I've used them and they work pretty well.

Comment: hmm...i don't know if i'm doing something wrong, but i can't seem to install it...
I downloaded it, and ran python2 setup.py build, but I get 'src/sfml.cpp:278:29: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory'...??

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: Your question was for libraries that will play MP3s, which people have delivered answers for. It's a bit much to then continue to ask these people for help on each step of the installation of these libraries. If you have a problem installing/using the libraries, perhaps you should go to any support site for the library, and if you are still stuck, consider asking another question on stackoverflow to help you with the installation.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik Please read [the documentation](http://pysfml2-cython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/building.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a [music player project](https://github.com/albertz/music-player) right now and along the way, I have developed a Python module which provides a very high-level interface to play all kind of audio files. It uses FFmpeg and PortAudio.

This is the module: [ffmpeg](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/ffmpeg.c)

For compiling on Linux, see the Readme; you might need a recent FFmpeg / PortAudio version; at least the versions in Debian were too old.

A simple demo example player based on this module is [here](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/test_ffmpeg.py).

Comment: I get 'OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''' on running compile.py...??

Comment: Have you installed all the dependencies, etc.? See the Readme for more info. Maybe you need to update compile.py for your system.